# Unable to start mongod daemon after upgrading OS from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, server, upgrade

***Unable to start mongod daemon after upgrading OS from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04***

```
root@dummy2:~# mongod --version
    db version v4.0.4
    git version: f288a3bdf201007f3693c58e140056adf8b04839
    OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
    allocator: tcmalloc
    modules: none
    build environment:
        distmod: ubuntu1804
        distarch: x86_64
        target_arch: x86_64


root@dummy2:~# 
cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"

root@dummy2:~# /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongo/db8303/mongodb.conf &
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4: version `CURL_OPENSSL_3' not found (required by /usr/bin/mongod)
```

The difference that I'm seeing before and after OS upgrade on libcurl version:

before:

```
root@dummy2:~# ls -lrt /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl*
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4 -> libcurl.so.4.4.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.3 -> libcurl.so.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4 -> libcurl-gnutls.so.4.4.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.3 -> libcurl-gnutls.so.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.4.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.4.0
```

After:

```
root@dummy2:~# ls -lrt /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4 -> libcurl.so.4.5.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4 -> libcurl-gnutls.so.4.5.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.3 -> libcurl-gnutls.so.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.5.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.5.0
```

***Did anyone face similar issues ?
How to fix this issue ?***

Comment: I've pasted output of OS release "cat /etc/*-release" in my question.

Comment: I edited my question and also I got the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried following different options :

Option1: with Ubuntu-16 mongo binaries (before option3 step2); if we are okay with libcurl3

```
1.  apt-get remove libcurl4
2.  apt-get install libcurl3
3.  able to start the daemon
```

Option2: didn’t work

```
1.  apt-get remove libcurl4
2.  apt-get install libcurl4
3.  /etc/init.d/mongo_db7020
/usr/bin/mongod: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4: version `CURL_OPENSSL_3' not found (required by /usr/bin/mongod)
```

Option3: copying mongodb 18 binaries worked

```
1.  apt-get remove libcurl4
2.  rsync -asvh mongoserver:/usr/bin/mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1804-4.0.4/bin/* /usr/bin/mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1604-4.0.4/bin
3.  apt-get install libcurl4
4.  able to start the daemon
```

Option 1 & 3 worked fine for me.